# Refreshing the Dock without actually killing it?

Tags: macos, dock

Is there a way to change Dock preferences and make the Dock app read the new one without using `killall Dock` command? Like to maybe force a refresh with some AppleScript or so?

Answer (score 1):

You might try

```
sudo pkill -1 Dock
```

which sends a ‘HANG-UP’ signal, also known as a ‘HUP’, to the process whose name matches Dock.  The expected response is an internal ‘stop and re-evaluate’ in which a relevant configuration file normally gets re-read.

F.

Comment: I'm away from my laptop, but will try as soon as I get back :) Thanks for an idea!